# Why won't my plane wrap all the way around a sphere? (Shrinkwrap modifier)

Tags: shrinkwrap

[image]

Why won't  my plane wrap all the way around a sphere?

[image]

I would like my plane to wrap around a sphere like in the picture above

Comment: Try changing the order of the modifiers

Comment: That does not help

Comment: When you are using project, the vertices that are not aligned with the target object are ignored. What are you trying to do? Why do you need the shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: @cegaton, I just edited my post again with an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Shrikwrap projects to the nearest face as far as I understand it. Maybe try to get your plane closer to your sphere, tilt it so as to be tangent to the sphere. Also, these are tris, not sure if it makes it worse.

Comment: Shrinkwrap won't magically rotate the plane and make it stick to the sphere somewhere below; it will try to move mesh along its normals if there is surface to snap to below. As surface happens to be spheric it isn't everywhere below but only partially so that's what actually gets shrinkwrapped in the end. Rotate the plane in Edit mode to make modifier see where to snap to